# TF30279: Plug-in with ID "Microsoft.ProjectCreationWizard.Build" of type "Project Creation Plugins" could not be loaded

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2012

When attempting to create a new TFS Team Project from VS2012 I received the following error after pressing finish.

TF30279: Plug-in with ID "Microsoft.ProjectCreationWizard.Build" of type "Project Creation Plugins" could not be loaded

TFS and VS were both installed on a Windows 7 laptop for evaluation. When setting up TFS I configured the build server without error.

In attempting to get round the problem I uninstalled all 2012 components VS, TFS and Sql Server, then reinstalled them. I tried both TFS express and VS2012 for web express and full TFS trial and VS2012 premium trial (to rule out that it wasn't an issue with the express versions)

Each time the error would persist across re-installs.

Answer (score 3):

Although I could not find why the problem has occurred I did eventually manage to fix the issue after reading up on process templates and understanding where the plugin models were sourced from.

1) I opened VS2012 command prompt and ran as admin

2) changed dir to  %programfiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer

3) ran gacutil /i for each dll in the folder that looked like it was anything to do with build.